# SailsJS Failed to reload ORM hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

After installing the `sails-auth` and `sails-permissions` package my autoreload hook (https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload) doesn't work anymore:

> error: Failed to reload ORM hook. Details: Error: Failed to reinitialize ORM because the initialize() method of the ORM hook returned an error.
>   Details:
>   Error: Consistency violation: Instantiated Waterline model already has a datastore property.

Packages:

```
"bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
"ejs": "2.3.4",
"grunt": "0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-coffee": "0.13.0",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.9.0",
"grunt-contrib-jst": "0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-less": "1.1.0",
"grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.7.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
"grunt-sails-linker": "~0.10.1",
"grunt-sync": "0.2.4",
"include-all": "~0.1.6",
"marlinspike": "^1.0.0",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"rc": "1.0.1",
"sails": "~0.12.3",
"sails-auth": "^2.1.3",
"sails-disk": "~0.10.9",
"sails-hook-autoreload": "^0.13.1",
"sails-permissions": "^2.2.0",
"validator": "^5.2.0"
```

Sails version v0.12.3.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can You show us Your model files?

Comment: User.js and passport.js: https://gist.github.com/nehalist/e7b55f1303b1af36023c815eda7731ae